# Pass data from child component to child component

Tags: angular5, parent-child

I have inside a parent component, two child component app-search & app-list as follows:

```
<app-search-panel (searchedParam)="childEventClicked($event)"></app-search-panel>
<app-list-panel [event]="searchedParam"></app-list-panel>
```

Inside app-search, I have a form which when submit the value is to be passed to second child.

```
childEventClicked(event: any){
        console.log("dashboard", event);
        this.searchedParam = event;
    }
```

### app-search-panel.ts

```
@Output() searchedParam = new EventEmitter();

onSubmit() {
 this.searchedParam.emit(cityName);
}
```

### list-panel.ts

```
@Input() event: any;
```

I am not being able to get the value at this component.

Can anybody please help me. what mistake I have did.

THank You.

Comment: can you please share more code? especially list-panel.ts and app-search-panel.html and what do you mean by "I am not being able to get the value at this component" What happens when you replace `@Input() event: any;` with a setter?

Answer (score 0):

@Input, @Output will work only when components ara parent and child, in your case both childrens are sibilings, So you can't do direct intaraction between two children componets

Solutions:

1> Pass the data to child1-->Parent---> child2
2> use subject or behaviour subject to communicate two components.

you can find it for refence for second solution

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/07/angular-7-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject